# Memory management - redundant copies

Tags: objective-c

Is there any difference between:

```
@synthesize something;
…
NSObject *tempThing = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.something = tempThing;
[tempThing release];
```

and

```
@synthesize something;
…
self.something =  [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

The first version seems redundant, but I suspect it may have a benefit that I'm not seeing, because I see it in many examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the property is declared retain e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id something;
```

then when you call

```
self.something = newValue;

// OR (the two are equivalent)

[self setSomething:newValue];
```

the setter implementation will take a retain on `newValue`.

Therefore

```
   retain +1             retain +1
       |                     |
+------------+    +---------------------+
|            |    |                     |
self.something =  [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

If you `release` the ivar `something` in `dealloc` then you will still have a `+1` retain, which you will not have been released.

To correct this either use your first method (which is preferable) or add an `autorelease`

```
self.something =  [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

**So why use the first method? / Why do you see this in examples?**

In memory constrained environments it's good to be in control of your memory. So you should explicitly release things when they are no longer to make the most of the environment.

Comment: Thanks Paul.s - a very clear description of a (to me) non-intuitive issue.

Comment: @Andrew Take extra care with those property attributes.  If a property declaration does not have "retain" listed, then you don't want to release or autorelease, or you'll get a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on the property of `something`;
if it is `retain`, first approach is correct  while second version , you are retaining `something` twice. Hence second approach should be
`something = [NSObject alloc] init];`

if it is `assign` , first approach wont retain `something`, hence it should be
`self.something = [tempThing retain];`

Comment: Thanks @Tatvamasi.  The property is retain, so is "something=[[NSObject alloc]init];" the best alternative?  I thought that referring to properties without using the setter was not good practice, but in this case it seems to do what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The two examples of code are definitely different, but their actual behavior depends on your property's declaration.

1. If property `something` has the `assign` attribute, then the top example leaves the first NSObject allocated with a net retain count of 0, and the bottom example with a net retain count of 1.
2. If property `something` has the `retain` attribute: top = count of 1 on first NSObject, bottom = count of 2 on first NSObject
3. If property `something` has the `copy` attribute: top = count of 0 on first NSObject + count of 1 on second NSObject (because copy allocs a second instance!), bottom = count of 1 on first NSObject (**First NSObject is also LEAKED!**), + count of 1 on second NSObject.

Here's your examples with some comments to explain better:

```
@synthesize something;
…
NSObject *tempThing = [[NSObject alloc] init]; //1st NSObject: +1 retain count
self.something = tempThing;     //1st NSObject: +0 if assign or copy, +1 if retain
                                //2nd NSObject: +1 if copy
[tempThing release];            //1st NSObject: -1 retain count
```

-

```
@synthesize something;
…
self.something =  [[NSObject alloc] init]; //2nd NSObject: +1 if copy
                               //1st NSObject: +1 if assign or copy, +2 if retain
```

More info on property attributes here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html